# pegar o resultado de uma função e enviar via post em outra

Tags: javascript, qrcode

estou usano a lib instascan para ler qr code. mas não estou conseguindo enviar o resultado via post com ajax. alguem pode ajudar?

O código que estou usando está abaixo:

qr sacanner

```
<h1>qr scanner</h1>

<video id="preview"></video>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
  scanner.addListener('scan', function lerQrcode(content) {
    //alert(content);
    gravar(content);
    document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = content;

  });

  function gravar(){        
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "dados.php",
            data: '', // aqui deveria executar o post dos dados lidos
            success: function(data){                                
                alert(data.teste);
            }
        });
}


  Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
    if (cameras.length > 0) {
      scanner.start(cameras[0]);
    } else {
      console.error('No cameras found.');
    }
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
  // executar o post


</script>
```

Comment: O data tá com o valor '', deveria ser content, não? Pra isso você criaria uma variável global pra receber o valor de content no listener do scanner e passaria no atributo data essa variável.

Answer (score 0):

Você está chamando a função `gravar(content)` enviando o valor de `content`, então deve colocar na função o respectivo parâmetro para receber esse valor, e jogar no data do Ajax:

```
function gravar(content){
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "dados.php",
      data: { codigo: content },
      success: function(data){                                
         alert(data.teste);
      }
   });
}
```

Na página PHP (`dados.php`) você recebe o valor com `$_POST['codigo']`.